# Gradient of matrix and Hadamart product

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

The matrix problem is given by: $$y=M^T * A \circ B$$
where $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^m, A,B\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\times\mathbb{R}^n$

$\circ$ is Hadamart (element-wise) product and $*$ is matrix multiplication.

How do I find $\frac {\partial y} {\partial A}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will be a 4th order tensor, it's not straightforward to represent it using matrix notation. More generally, how do you define the derivative of a matrix with respect to another matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The componentwise gradient of a matrix with respect to its own elements is given by
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\grad{A}{A_{ij}} &= {E_{ij}} \\
}$$
where $E_{ij}$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ component is equal $\tt1$ and all others are equal to $0$.

Using this, the componentwise gradient of your function is
$$\eqalign{
&Y = M^T\LR{A\circ B} \\
&\grad{Y}{A_{ij}} = M^T\LR{E_{ij}\circ B} \\
&\grad{Y}{A_{ij}} = M^T{B_{ij}} \\
}$$
where $B_{ij}$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)$ component is equal to the corresponding component of $B$ and all other components are equal to $0$.

The full gradient can be constructed by summing over the components using a dyadic/tensor product (denoted by the $\star$ symbol)
$$\eqalign{
\def\S{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n}
\grad{Y}{A}
 &= \S \LR{\grad{Y}{A_{ij}}}\star E_{ij} \\\\
}$$
Your other option is to [use vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) to flatten the equation into a vector form
$$\eqalign{
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\!\BR{\!#1}}
\vecc{Y} &= \LR{I_n\otimes M^T}\Diag{\vecc{B}}\vecc{A} \\
\grad{\vecc{Y}}{\vecc{A}} &= \LR{I_n\otimes M^T}\Diag{\vecc{B}} \\
}$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.